# Debug C# web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, debugging

I have a web service project and simple test application. I can debug the web service from Visual Studio 2008. However, there exist a real client application, but it is on another machine. ASP.NET Development Server does not allow connections if they are not from localhost, or so it seems. Is there a way to debug a web service, if client application is on another machine?

Edit

The tool that I used is Trace Utility from [Microsoft SOAP Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450). Further explanation can be found [here](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2009/09/03/accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-from-iphone.aspx) (works on XP; see [continuation story](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2010/08/18/iphone-accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-windows-7-update.aspx) for Windows 7 solution). There was problem with it though. My remote client fetches the WSDL first, and then creates URL based on values in soap tags found at the end of WSDL. So client gets redirected to localhost, which is not good.

I found my problem though, but I'll leave the question open until I find the time to try debugging via IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a virtual directory into the IIS on your local machine. If you don't have IIS, install it. Once IIS is installed and configured on your local machine, you should be able to use either the IP or create a dns alias for that IP to access the web service that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [SoapUI](http://www.eviware.com/soapUI/soapui-products-overview.html) basic version to fake the SOAP requests to the web service, which is running in debug mode in Visual Studio, from the local computer.

Comment: I have a client application, so I don't need to fake requests. Can SoapUI be used as a proxy between my client application and web service?

Comment: Nope, it's a program to interact to SOAP services, like a web browser is to web pages. Maybe won't resolve your problem, but it's an handy tool when developing locally (and may be used if you won't be able to use your remote application).

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS (or [Cassini Web server](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/)) - for debugging, attach VS 2008 to correct process (for example w3p.exe(IIS6 or greater) or aspnet_wp.exe(IIS 5)).

Comment: I'm trying to evaluate Cassini Web Server, but my development machine is not online. Official site gives me only a stub exe, and expects internet connection. Is there a link to offline installer?